# Создание приложения на ionic для старых версий андроид

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, ionic

Создаю приложение под андроид на ionic framework. Столкнулся с проблемой что на версиях андроид от 5.0.0 и выше приложение работает замечательно, но на версиях андроид 4.0, 4.2 и др то едет вёрстка, то не работает некоторый функционал. Я недавно познакомился с ionic и cordova и так и не понял как работают такие приложения. Кажется проблема кроется в поддержке js и css в браузерах на старых версиях андроид. Есть ли способ нормализовать работу приложения на старых моделях смартфонов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам нужно:
[Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) - это опенсорсный продукт, позволяющий на старых версиях Android (4.0-4.3) использовать не встроенный WebView, а Chrome WebView, указывая нужную версию.